# Are Siddhis Illusory and part of Maya?

Tags: maya, buddhism, siddhi

When Buddha and some other ascended masters attained enlightenment were gifted with special abilities or [Siddhis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhi). Buddha was even able to recall his previous lives and his and other people's karmas but how can we know those were real a not a creation of [Maya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_(religion))?

Are Siddhis also illusory in nature?

Comment: Maya can also be real as far as I understand. Can I ask what you define as maya?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes siddhis are illusionary just like senses and is a temptation or a bait of God to raise a man to higher realm for no Siddhi is possible without sadhna, yoga, self-restrain.

[what-is-recommended-meditation-to-know-everything-about-self-and-surrounding](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36457/what-is-recommended-meditation-to-know-everything-about-self-and-surrounding/36473#36473)

> One day, Sri Ramakrishna took Narendra to the Panchavati and told him,
>   'Look, I possess the eight occult powers. But I decided long ago that
>   I would never use them and I find no need for them. But you will have
>   to preach religion and do many other things. I have decided to give
>   those powers to you. Please accept them.' **Narendra asked in reply,
>   'Will they help me realize God?' When Sri Ramakrishna explained that
>   they might help to some extent in preaching religion but would not
>   help him attain God-realization, Narendra declined those powers.**

The desire to possess siddhis is same as desire of possessing something by the false non-luminous ego and mind of Prakriti which is inert in reality. Everyone desires to be Omnipotent, immortal and beautiful, the desire comes from Purusha/soul.

[Patanjali Yoga Sutras](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_1/Raja-Yoga/Patanjali%27s_Yoga_Aphorisms_-_Independence)

> 38. These are obstacles to Samadhi; but they are powers in the worldly state.
> 39. By giving up even these powers comes the destruction of the very seed of evil, which leads to Kaivalya.
> 40. **The states of the mind are always known, because the lord of the mind, the Purusha, is unchangeable.**
>
> **18. The mind is not self-luminous, being an object.**
>
> 23. The mind, though variegated by innumerable desires, acts for another (the Purusha), because it acts in combination.
> 24. For the discriminating, the perception of the mind as Atman ceases.
> 25. Then, bent on discriminating, the mind attains the previous state of Kaivalya (isolation).

Comment: I am not sure I agree. Siddhis can be obtained via appropiate mantra's and meditation. They are supernatural powers. Supernatural is not a part of maya correct.